# using ppDisp to take control of popup windows in userform

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have setup a userform1 to browse an intranet using web browser controls in VBA/Excel.  The problem I am having is that when the user initiates a popup through the web browser control, that popup runs in IE by default, outside of the scope of the web browser control, and therefore doesnt contain the correct session data in the popup.  This popup initiates from a dropdown box, onchange command and then inserts the input from the popup back into a web form on the page.  The code below intercepts the popup event and lets you handle it, by transferring it to say, userform2

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow2(ppDisp As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim frm As UserForm2
'Dim ppDisp As Object

Set frm = New UserForm2

Set ppDisp = frm.WebBrowser1.Application

frm.Show

End Sub
```

Problem is, it gets stuck right now on frm.show, when I pause, and doesnt seem to be actively transferring over the web page correctly into userform2.  I'm not sure where my logic is wrong here, any advice would be helpful.  Most guides have shown:

```
Set ppDisp = frm.WebBrowser1.object
```

But I cant find that in the object browser anywhere, and doing .object bombs out, as error 438: object doesnt support this property or method.  But everything I could find on this so far shows using .object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone reading this, VBA wont support this method as the above says.  It works perfectly in .net and I would assume then, vb6